# Removing pages from PDF is not performing as expected

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have written following Java code:

```
PDDocument document=PDDocument.load(file);
int noOfPages= document.getNumberOfPages();
System.out.println(noOfPages);
boolean bq=document.removePage(2);
System.out.println(bq);
boolean bq1=document.removePage(3);
System.out.println(bq1);
boolean bq2=document.removePage(4);
System.out.println(bq2);
```

And getting the output as:

```
5
true
true
false
```

I can't understand why the **page** with the index **`4` is not removed**.

When I am using only

```
boolean bq2=document.removePage(4);
```

it is working fine, page got deleted from PDF.

Comment: It seems that when you removed page 2 and 3 the document get reordered.  For example: when you removed page 2, page 3 and 4 now are page 2 and 3. When you removed page 3, page 4 is now page 3, that's why you cannot remove page 4.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 pages. These have the numbers 0 1 2 3 4. After removing page 2 you have pages 0 1 2 3. After removing page 3 you have pages 0 1 2. Thus you won't be able to remove page 4, because it doesn't exist.

A solution would be to start with the last page#.

An alternative solution would be to retrieve the pages to get PDPage objects before doing the removals, and use these as argument for removePage.